# Is it possible to build a LibreOffice sidebar addon with HTML,CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno

Just wondering if its possible to build side bar add-ons for LibreOffice/OpenOffice with HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The other alternative idea would be to use the UNO api and an embedded browser to display a web app and allow interaction. We have a single base for Google Apps and Microsoft Office built as a web app. If we can use a browser and the UNO api then we can have LibreOffice as a deploy target too from the same codebase. Has this been done before?

Any ideas or help would be really appreciated. :)

This is an example of the app that Ill be porting over (all sample data):

### Google Apps:

[image]

### Excel for iPad

[image]

### Excel for Mac

[image]

### Excel Online (Office 365)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions on [this page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Sidebar_for_Developers) for building a panel via an extension (*NOT* via the C++ core).

The primary file to create is called `Sidebar.xcu`.  Several other files are needed as well.  There is an example of all of these files further down on the page.

The example is written in Java, and it may be easier to implement the whole sidebar in Java rather than Javascript/CSS/HTML.  However it is possible to [write extensions using Javascript](https://www.openoffice.org/framework/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html).

Comment: Hi @Jim,
Thanks for the documentation details. They were really helpful. Just wondering on the second option of embedding a browser into the sidebar if you've seen this done or if there are any docs/code samples/libs for doing this?

Comment: I do not think LibreOffice has a [web browser control](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=79406).  Also, if you found the answer to be helpful, then please mark it as accepted.