# Creating a сustom side panel using the LibreOffice SDK

Tags: python, sdk, libreoffice-calc

Good afternoon.

I had the following question:

How to use the LibreOffice SDK and Python to create a custom side panel in LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: The SDK is not needed for Python-UNO. It's only for compiled languages such as Java and C++. Also, what has your research uncovered so far? For example, my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052620/5100564, or instead of programming, attach a custom toolbar.

Comment: Is my code, but it doesn't fit: `dialog = self.__serviceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialog", self.__context)
dialogModel = self.__serviceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.awt.UnoControlDialogModel", self.__context) dialogModel.setPropertyValues(("Sizeable","Height", "Width", "Title",),  (True, 100, 100, "Data",))
    dialog.setModel(dialogModel)
    dialog.setVisible(True)     
    dialogState: int = dialog.execute()`

Comment: Instead of adding code in a comment where it doesn't fit, edit the question and post a complete, reproducible code sample, along with more context — is this code giving an error, and if so, what is the error? What do you expect it to do? Where did you get the code from? It looks like the code is for creating a dialog, but I don't see how that relates to your stated goal of creating a sidebar.